# go-jira command line to force input from a file instead of the editor

Tags: jira

I use the command line go-jira from Netflix to automate some tasks with JIRA. In certain circumstances I am asked to enter a multi-line input content through an editor. For example with the command:

> jira.exe create --editor="notepad++.exe"

The program then expects me to save the file of the editor and then go-jira completes the action by picking up the saved file. The file format is BTW YML.

Is there a way to tell go-jira to use automatically an existing file instead of using the interactive editor?